# What do all of the 'Re-up' symbols look like?

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

In Gears of Way Judgement, you can re-up - similar to the 'prestiging' in Call of Duty.  The problem is though, I would like to know how many times my opponents have re-uped.   The current symbol for re-up #1 looks like a bronze star.   I think the #2 re-up looks like a bronze star with a circle around it.   Can anyone help me out with some sort of key or reference ? I heard you can re-up 11 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The re-up symbols cycle through a star, a star with a circle background, a star with a COG symbol background:<sup>[1](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/945687-Re-Up-rank-quot-symbols-quot?p=31089684&viewfull=1#post31089684)</sup>

- Re-up #1: bronze star
- Re-up #2: bronze star with circle background
- Re-up #3: bronze star with COG symbol background
- Re-up #4: silver star
- Re-up #5: silver star with circle background
- Re-up #6: silver star with COG symbol background
- Re-up #7: (unconfirmed) gold star
- Re-up #8: (unconfirmed) gold star with circle background
- Re-up #9: (unconfirmed) gold star with COG symbol background
- Re-up #10: (unconfirmed) wings

Comment: 6th re-up.... in two days ?@!@!@!@  Whaaaaaaaaatttttt?   Also, thanks for finding this !

Answer (score -1):

You can only re-up 3 times and the first time you re-up it's a star its color is bronze when your on the red team and silver when your on the blue team and second re-up is star with a triangle kind of shape with star in it I haven't run someone who has re-upped to 3 yet

Comment: Re up 3 is a star with a cog around it..i read you can reup 11 times..thats what they said in the epic forums